# Complexity of getting all neighbors of all nodes in adjacency list/matrix

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory

If I want to get all the neighbors of one node in a graph, the time complexity is O(|V|) if the graph is stored in an adjacency matrix and also O(|V|) if it's saved in an adjacency list. Now I was thinking, how this would change if I did not want to get the neighbors of one node but instead all nodes. (Note: The adjacency list contains an array and linked lists. One linked list is stored at each array entry, where each array entry represents one node. Each node in the linked list represents an adjacent node.)

My though process is the following:

In an adjacency matrix I would need to have a look at every single entry. Therefore my time complexity is O(|V|^2). 
In an adjacency list I would need to look at each array entry and go through their respective linked list. I am thinking, that this should be done in O(|E|) because I basically just look at all edges.

Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity will be O(n + m) where n = number of vertex in graph & m = number of edges in graph.
You just need to apply BFS or DFS algorithm.

Comment: This is the case for an adjacency **list**, but the OP is correct in their analysis of the complexity for an adjacency **matrix**.

Comment: In case of adjacency matrix time complexity becomes O(v^2).

Comment: Exactly. The OP asked about both, and the adjacency matrix analysis was missing from your answer. To provide a complete answer, you might also explain why the adjacency list is `O(n+m)` instead of simply `O(m)`.